# What to do with upload ID beginning with dash (hyphen-minus)?

Tags: backup, upload, amazon-glacier

I'm having a bit of an issue when it comes to Amazon Glacier.

I typed in the command

```
aws glacier initiate-multipart-upload \
    --account-id - \
    --archive-description "Qozu Chronicles May 2023 Backup" \
    --part-size 4294967296 \
    --vault-name tyllavideo
```

and got the following result:

```
{
    "location": "/953374234641/vaults/tyllavideo/multipart-uploads/-BbO80kesvItrSPcGdZrfhco87xzs1oPdWG4r1WW7lJ1aTjElIICKthnMnkFuFjej8k4kWvJvaOQFNXGufCfYNKKSuiW",
    "uploadId": "-BbO80kesvItrSPcGdZrfhco87xzs1oPdWG4r1WW7lJ1aTjElIICKthnMnkFuFjej8k4kWvJvaOQFNXGufCfYNKKSuiW"
}
```

Note that the `uploadId` starts with a `-`.  This becomes a problem when I want to upload a part, as when I run the command

```
aws glacier upload-multipart-part \
    --upload-id -BbO80kesvItrSPcGdZrfhco87xzs1oPdWG4r1WW7lJ1aTjElIICKthnMnkFuFjej8k4kWvJvaOQFNXGufCfYNKKSuiW \
    --body chunkaa \
    --range 'bytes 0-6717640/*' \
    --account-id - \
    --vault-name tyllavideo
```

I get this error:

```
aws: error: argument --upload-id: expected one argument
```

I tried enclosing the `uploadId` in quotes, and I tried using a `\` to escape the `-`.  Both gave the same error.  What am I doing wrong, and how do I get the upload started?

Comment: did you try single quotes the same way `--range` is handled? Not sure what you are using aws cli in, but you can store the uploadId as a variable and then pass it in. In powershell - `$uploadId="-Bb08...."` then `aws glacier..... --upload-id $uploadId`

Comment: @Narzard single quotes did not work, and I am using Bash on a Linux machine.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1550#issuecomment-146488782

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski unfortunately that just gives me a different error: ```An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the UploadMultipartPart operation: The upload ID was not found: <-BbO80kesvItrSPcGdZrfhco87xzs1oPdWG4r1WW7lJ1aTjElIICKthnMnkFuFjej8k4kWvJvaOQFNXGufCfYNKKSuiW>```

Comment: I don't think `<` and `>` are meant to be literal. Or did you try `--upload-id='-Bb…'`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, I tried the single quotes both with and without the `<` and `>`.  Without, it gave the same error from my original question.  With, it gave the error I @'d you about earlier.

Comment: The single-quotes are least important. `=` is most important. Doesn't help, oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is mentioned in the bug report
 [aws glacier fails to work with archiveID's which start with a hyphen (-) #1319](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1319) .

This post relates to `archiveId`, but the suggested syntax
will probably also work for `uploadId` instead.

The suggested workarounds all use methods for avoiding specifying
directly the uploadId in the command.

Workaround 1 : Using the JSON parameter input method instead of the normal command-line inputs:

```
aws glacier delete-archive --account-id - --vault-name myvault --cli-input-json '{"archiveId": "-test"}'
```

Workaround 2 : Use the argument syntax `name='value'`:

```
aws glacier delete-archive --account-id '-' --vault-name myvault --archive-id='-test'
```

Comment: Workaround 1 worked!  Thanks!